# Code coverage for source files using lcov

Tags: c, lcov

I am using lcov and genhtml to generate code coverage reports. With the following directory structure, I am able to get the code coverage for the source files located in the tests/ directory, but am unable to get code coverage for the my_file.c file in my src/ directory.

```
src/
   my_file.c
   my_file.h
tests/
   AllTests.c
   CuTest.c
   CuTest.h
   my_file_tests.c

   objects/
       AllTests.gcda
       AllTests.gcno
       AllTests.o
       CuTest.gcda
       CuTest.gcno
       CuTest.o
       my_file.gcda
       my_file.gcno
       my_file.o
       my_file_tests.gcda
       my_file_tests.gcno
       my_file_tests.o
```

Invoking the lcov command from the tests directory:

`lcov -b . --directory objects/ -c -o ./coverage/app.info`

```
Capturing coverage data from objects/
Found gcov version: 4.4.3
Scanning objects/ for .gcda files ...
Found 4 data files in objects/
Processing objects/AllTests.gcda
Processing objects/my_file_test.gcda
Processing objects/CuTest.gcda
Processing objects/my_file.gcda
geninfo: WARNING: gcov did not create any files for /home/me/workspace/project/tests/objects/my_file.gcda!
Finished .info-file creation
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrading from lcov 1.7 to 1.9 fixed this issue for me. Version 1.9 is available from http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov.php